# Firebase A/B Testing User Limits

Tags: firebase, firebase-remote-config, ab-testing, firebase-ab-testing

Does Firebase A/B testing have a maximum number of users that can be included in an experiment? I've set up several experiments and they seem to always max out at 20k users. I don't see anything in the docs. Is there a known limit?

Answer (score 0):

There is no limit, we routinely have experiments running with hundreds of thousands of users... are you seeing it stop at exactly 20k? If you keep seeing this please reach out to support and we can figure something out.